# Method 'AddChart' of objects 'Shapes' failed

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, powerpoint

I have been generating PowerPoint presentations from Access 2010. Recently, I started seeing an error for some users where the [AddChart method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745740(v=office.14).aspx) failed. I have not been able to find any documentation on this error from Microsoft, and the only two results I could find here were [trying to create a slide during a slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437757/run-time-error-when-adding-chart-during-powerpoint-slideshow) and [running PowerPoint on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547281/we-are-facing-an-issue-to-generate-graph-on-the-slide-because-in-powerpoint-on-m). I am creating a new presentation from a generic template that is used for many different presentations.

The error generated is Error #-2147417846 ("Method 'AddChart' of object 'Shapes' failed"). I have also started getting an error that appears to be identical, but the error # is -2147467259.

I have Office 2010 on Windows 7, and I am collecting version info when the errors occur. Below is the code that is producing the error and the object definitions.

```
'Object definitions
Dim pptSld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim pptCht As PowerPoint.Chart
Dim xlsWbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsWks As Excel.Worksheet
```

...

```
'Use fncSlideCheck to add a new slide
Set pptSld = fncSlideCheck(pptPrs, pptSld)
pptSld.Select

Set pptShp = pptSld.Shapes.AddChart(xlLine)
Set pptCht = pptShp.Chart
Set xlsWbk = pptCht.ChartData.Workbook
```

**Update (11/14/17)**

I was able to catch the error manually once, and I got a dialog box reporting that the addchart method will not work if MS Excel is in edit mode or has a dialog box open. I found an Excel process running in the Task Manager and killed that process. Once I did that, the error ceased.

Comment: Looking up in the docs, the `Shapes` object in PowerPoint doesn't seem to have an `AddChart` method, only [AddChart2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/shapes-addchart2-method-powerpoint). It's possible the Office API in your version has changed since your last run I suppose.

Comment: I am using the office 14.0 libraries. AddChart2 is not a available method for the PowerPoint.Slide.Shapes object. I check the object browser for hidden methods as well, and it was not available.

The Office API may be the issue, and I am investigating that. Not all users are having the issue, so it seems reasonable. I will edit the post to clarify that.